# Joomla call function

Tags: joomla

I have a joomla3 site, and want to call function from plugin in joomla template.  For that I write in template this code `<?php echo  my_function($id);?>`.

In plugin class I have

```
class plgSystemMyPlugin extends JPlugin {...}
function my_function($id) { echo $id; }
```

But  when I refresh the page I get

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

What's the problem, can anybody help me please?

Comment: improve format, removed windows tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello Marina**,

You should use as per below in your Joomla! template index.php :

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin( 'system' );
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$result = $dispatcher->trigger('MySpecificEvent', $arguments);
<?php echo  $result;?>
```

and in your system plugin that you created,

```
class plgSystemMyPlugin extends JPlugin {
    public function MySpecificEvent($id){
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works or not for you.

Thanks